# How to set the value for master page drop down in Child page

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have done some code in C#.net.
I have a drop down in Master page. This drop down is loading correctly, but when I try to select a value in the drop down and try to submit the page, that page is loading after the current page load. Even I don't have selected value in the drop down instead of that I have default value as selected value.

How to set the value for drop down in Child page?

Comment: <%Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="true"  EnableViewStateMac="true";

Comment: Can you share you code what you did earlier.

Comment: <%Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="true" EnableViewStateMac="true"; @mantu this in Child page

Comment: mmm code would help and in fact its one of the requirements for asking a question on SO

Comment: Search for IsPostBack to manage this scenario.